# Create-Delete Buttons

Tags: user-interface, button, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make two buttons in Tkinter using python version 3.3, one to create a button and one to delete said button. It has been working so far except for the fact that if I create more than one button I can only delete one the the created buttons. My question is: is there anything I can do to be able to delete a button every time the delete button is called upon?
This is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
def createbutton():
    global secondbut
    secondbut=Button(root,text="button")
    secondbut.pack()
def eliminatebutton():
    secondbut.destroy()
if __name__=='__main__':
    root=Tk()
    global create
    global delete
    create= Button(root,text="create",command=createbutton)
    delete=Button(root,text="delete",command=eliminatebutton)
    create.pack()
    delete.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're storing your `Button` in a variable (`secondbut`), then overwriting that variable if you create a new button.

Instead of directly storing it in a variable, store it in some container, such as a list.

This code will do what you want:

```
from tkinter import *
def createbutton():
    global secondbut
    secondbut.append(Button(root,text="button"))
    secondbut[-1].pack()
def eliminatebutton():
    secondbut[-1].destroy()
    secondbut.pop()
if __name__=='__main__':
    root=Tk()
    global create
    global delete
    global secondbut
    secondbut = []
    create= Button(root,text="create",command=createbutton)
    delete=Button(root,text="delete",command=eliminatebutton)
    create.pack()
    delete.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Note that it removes buttons in the *opposite* order it adds them.

Comment: thanks, this was very helpful. I was just wondering if I add a command to the button secondbut, will that be overwritten as well with each new button created. or will each button in the list hold their own command?

Comment: Each button will hold its own command - remember, `secondbut` itsn't a single button anymore, it's a list of buttons.